CSS not applied to img in ASP.NET
I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC project and I'm trying to apply some css to an image.
Project structure
And this is the code:
//Index.cshtml.css
h1 {
    color: green
}

.roundImage {
    border-radius: 50px;
}

#profilePhoto {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 2rem 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

//Index.cshtml
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">My name</h1>
    <img class='roundImage' id="profilePhoto" src="~/images/me.jpg" alt="Profile photo" />
</div>

The color of the h1 is being applied but I have tryed both approaches for the img and it did not work. Why is that and how could I fix it?

Firstly, <img> is a built-in Tag Helper. We can also notice the differences between tag helper and normal html element in VS.

Then due to tag helper occurred at runtime while css isolation occurred at build time, css isolation classes are not able to apply to tag helper. Just like we can see, img tag isn't applied the unique identifier, while the div and h1 tags are having it.

So the solutions are preventing <img> tag to be recognized as tag helper, or put the class for <img> out of css isolation. Per my test, using opt-out character "!" like <!img> doesn't work for our scenario. Just like the screenshot below, the identifier of CSS isolation will break the html tag. So that I still recommend to put the class definition out of css isolation file.


Thanks for your answer.
Using this approach (adding the b-... identifier) is a kind of a fix or is it a standard? Also, if I, for instance, launched this app on a server, the identifier would be the same?
Since I'm new to ASP.NET I'm trying to find out the better way of implementing CSS. I don't know if I should write it all in the wwwroot folder or if using CSS isolation is better...

the identifier would be the same -> different.  I don't know if I should write it all in the wwwroot folder or if using CSS isolation is better --> writing in CSS isolation helps  the class not to affect other cshtmls. If you don't have such requirements, then it's ok for you to write all into wwwroot folder. If you want some specific pages to use specific styles, then CSS isolation will help you. @apda

The cshtml.css will add a scope-identifier:
You can open developer mode in the browser and see the h1 tag is working with the color green.

BUT you will see the CSS styles are with an id [b-34vq99bu2v]

That is the reason the CSS is not working for the image.
You can add the scope id inside img like:
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">My name</h1>
    <img b-34vq99bu2v class='roundImage' id="profilePhoto" src="~/images/ILTW.png" alt="Profile photo" />
</div>

Then that will work.

Reference: Razor Pages - CSS Isolation - styles for some HTML tags are not working
